# Color is not changing by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, runtime-error

I am trying to change the color of thermometer which I get from font awesome but now when i am trying to change it's color so at that time it's not working and when i assign new variable on top of my function to check is there any problem with my code which i wrote in my function although the new variable is assigned completely  right but after assigning the new variable on top the rest of the code stop working, if i comment the new variable which i created on top the code start working perfectly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
      <title>Document</title>
      <style>
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        .container{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;`your text`
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="heading">I am <br> Thermometer <span id="icon"></span></h1>
       

        
    </div>


    <script>
         const heading = document.getElementsByClassName("heading")
         heading.style.color="red";

        const thermometer = ()=>{
            let temp = document.getElementById("icon")

            temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-empty"></i>'
            

            setTimeout(()=>{
                temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-quarter"></i>';
                temp.style.Color ="#d63031"
                
            },1000);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-half"></i>';
            },2000)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-three-quarters"></i>'
            },3000)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-full"></i>'
                
            },4000)

        }

        thermometer()

        setInterval(thermometer,5000)
    </script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c672f3d7e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a typo.  It should be a lowercase C on color :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, the syntax is `color` you've used an uppercase.

`const heading = document.getElementsByClassName("heading");` should be `document.querySelector('heading');`, otherwise console errors as it's expecting several elements.

You're also assigning the color to the `<span id='icon'></span>` and not the icon itself, see code I'm sure you can think of a better way to implement this.

Here's the solution to fix it...

```js
 <script>
        const heading = document.querySelector('heading');
        heading.style.color = "red";



        const thermometer = () => {
        let temp = document.getElementById("icon")

            temp.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-empty"></i>'


            setTimeout(() => {
                temp.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-quarter" style="color: #d63031"></i>';
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(() => {
                temp.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-half"></i>';
            }, 2000)
            setTimeout(() => {
                temp.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-three-quarters"></i>'
            }, 3000)
            setTimeout(() => {
                temp.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-full"></i>'

            }, 4000)

        }

        thermometer();

        setInterval(thermometer, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, the issue is the syntax of color which i have resolved by my self after posting a question and the main issue is  i have to use querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName, once again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with your reset to set the color of **everything** to white.

```
* {color: white;}
```

Resets are a bad idea to begin with, but **especially** with color. The reason this is causing your code not to work is that you are changing the color of the `<span>`, but the `<i>` element inside it (implementing the font awesome icon), rather than inheriting from the `<span>` as it normally would, is **forced to white** by your blanket reset.

User agent stylesheets (browser default style) are there for a reason and they actually make your life as a web developer much easier. Don’t try to override them using the asterisk (*) selector.

Instead, just apply color at the body level and through normal inheritance this will apply to those elements for which color inheritance makes sense.

```
body {color: white;}
```

A snippet to demonstrate:

```js
const heading = document.querySelector(".heading")
heading.style.color="red"

const thermometer = () => {
  let temp = document.getElementById("icon")
  temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-empty"></i>'
  temp.style.color ="white"

  setTimeout(()=>{
    temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-quarter"></i>'
    temp.style.color ="lime"
  },1000)
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-half"></i>'
    temp.style.color ="yellow"
  },2000)

  setTimeout(()=>{
    temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-three-quarters"></i>'
    temp.style.color ="orange"
  },3000)

  setTimeout(()=>{
    temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-full"></i>'
    temp.style.color ="red"
  },4000)

}

thermometer()
setInterval(thermometer,5000)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c672f3d7e.js"></script>
      
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="heading">I am <br> Thermometer <span id="icon"></span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Javascript is case-sensitive

This line

```
          temp.style.Color ="#d63031"
```

should read:

```
          temp.style.color ="#d63031"
```

#### You may have been distracted because HTML/CSS is often case-insensitive

For example, you can call a tag `<DIV>` or `<div>` or even `dIv`. But Javascript variables and properties are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try add

```
style="color: red"
```

in to the temp.innerHTML.

like this:

```
style="color: red"
```

in to the temp.innerHTML.

like this:

```
temp.innerHTML='<i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-temperature-empty" style="color:red"></i>'
```

Comment: @Spectric Reference please, otherwise we are not learning...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i think you are right, but there are multiple ways to do it. And this is unfortunately one of them.